# How do I reinstall Python 3?

Tags: python-3

I cannot get pip to work and I think that reinstalling python 3.7 might help. When I try 'sudo apt install --reinstall python3' I get an error saying there are unmet dependencies. If I specify it to be python3.7 it can't locate the package.

Comment: Are "unmet dependencies" packages that python3 depends on, or packages which depend on python3?

Comment: What error do you get if you try to use pip or pip3?

Comment: yeah it says something with LibreOffice. I'm fine if that's messed up though I don't use it

Comment: This isn't the way to solve a PIP problem. You're turning it into an X-Y problem. Post a new question with the errors you get from PIP rather than your hare-brained idea to attempt to re-install Python. (Which won't work and will destroy your system).

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt-get purge python3

sudo apt-get install python3

might do the trick :)

Comment: Doing `sudo apt update` is also a good idea before reinstall.

Comment: Someone has reported **this can do very nasty things on a current (2022) install,** which makes sense if various important components (apparently including critical parts of the desktop) have migrated from python 2 to 3.