# No module named 'google' - OR - "The hard and long way it is to develop in Raspberry PI"

Tags: python, api

... Short story:

I have a Python program with just one line:

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
```

When I run it from the python3 command or from Thonny, I get this message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

I had installed modules on pi, and tried several "solutions" from the web, none of them worked (the libraries install ok, but the python script still fails with the same error):

```
pip install google-auth
pip install requests
pip install google-auth-oauthlib
pip install google-api-python-client
```

LONG STORY:

I had also installed those libraries ...

(those solutions were suggested on several web pages. I've just googled some hours... Some of them seem to be VERY UNRELATED TO MY PROBLEM, but hey, who knows...)

```
pip install google-api-core
pip install google.cloud.storage
pip install protobuf
pip install google
pip install google-auth
pip install google-cloud-vision
pip install google-cloud
pip install google-cloud-translate
pip install google.cloud.bigquery
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
pip install requests
```

And the last one, that made me SICK, was to reinstall python3. I'd followed the instructions here: [How do I reinstall Python 3?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100254/how-do-i-reinstall-python-3/136650#136650)

I did that, and as the answer there shows, I lost my Desktop, Thonny and who knows what !!!

So, just to keep developing and mortifying myself, how can I fix my PI and get that IMPORT working ?

Thanks for your patience and help !

Comment: you may have installed them for python 2 not python3 for python3 use pip3 to install.

Comment: There is nothing to "fix" on the Pi.  You need to install Python modules for the particular version(s) of Python you want to use.

Comment: Welcome.  The basic point with the duplicate is to use `pip3` for python3 modules.   There's also a distro package for google auth, have a look at `apt search python3-google`.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help, that worked (of course) !